# How to change the colors of an image and still have it reconized by the code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, vba

this is my first time asking a question here, so please be kind.

This is for a small game I'm making in Visual Basic 2010.  I have an image that, when clicked on, is darkened.  I need it to to be recognized later by the code as the same as the original image.

Here's the code to darken the image:

```
Sub WaterDarken(ByVal picTarget As PictureBox)
    Dim pic As New Bitmap(picTarget.Image)
    Dim intRed As Integer
    Dim intGreen As Integer
    Dim intBlue As Integer
    For x As Integer = 0 To picTarget.Image.Width - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To picTarget.Image.Height - 1
            Dim intDarkenedColor As Color = pic.GetPixel(x, y)
            If intDarkenedColor.R - 50 <= 255 And intDarkenedColor.R - 50 >= 0 Then
                intRed = intDarkenedColor.R - 50
            Else
                intRed = 0
            End If
            If intDarkenedColor.G - 50 <= 255 And intDarkenedColor.G - 50 >= 0 Then
                intGreen = intDarkenedColor.G - 50
            Else
                intGreen = 0
            End If
            If intDarkenedColor.B - 50 <= 255 And intDarkenedColor.B - 50 >= 0 Then
                intBlue = intDarkenedColor.B - 50
            Else
                intBlue = 0
            End If
            intDarkenedColor = Color.FromArgb(225, intRed, intGreen, intBlue)
            pic.SetPixel(x, y, intDarkenedColor)
        Next
    Next
    picTarget.Image = pic
End Sub
```

And here is the code to compare the original image to the darkened one:

```
  Function IsDarkened(ByRef source As Image, ByRef darkenedSource As Image) As Boolean
    Dim pic As New Bitmap(source)
    Dim pic2 As New Bitmap(darkenedSource)
    Dim intRed As Integer
    Dim intGreen As Integer
    Dim intBlue As Integer
    For x As Integer = 0 To pic.Width - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To pic.Height - 1
            Dim darkened As Color = pic.GetPixel(x, y)
            If darkened.R - 50 <= 255 And darkened.R - 50 >= 0 Then
                intRed = darkened.R - 50
            Else
                intRed = 0
            End If
            If darkened.G - 50 <= 255 And darkened.G - 50 >= 0 Then
                intGreen = darkened.R - 50
            Else
                intGreen = 0
            End If
            If darkened.B - 50 <= 255 And darkened.B - 50 >= 0 Then
                intBlue = darkened.B - 50
            Else
                intBlue = 0
            End If
            darkened = Color.FromArgb(255, intRed, intGreen, intBlue)
            pic.SetPixel(x, y, darkened)
        Next
    Next
    For x = 0 To pic.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To pic.Height - 1
            If pic.GetPixel(x, y) <> pic2.GetPixel(x, y) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

However, something isn't working, and the images aren't being noticed as the same.
This has been bothering me for some time.  If any of you can help, please do so!
Thanks.

Comment: Okay then.  I fixed the 225 vs. 255 thing, but IsDarkened still returns false at the first opportunity...
And I have no idea why!

Comment: Okay, it seems I was barking up the wrong tree.  I got it done another way.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Color.FromArgb(), you set the pixels to two different alpha values:

intDarkenedColor = Color.FromArgb(**225**, intRed, intGreen, intBlue)

vs.

darkened = Color.FromArgb(**255**, intRed, intGreen, intBlue)

Having the same RGB but different opacity will always result in different images.

Comment: Oops!  I always mix up 225 and 255.  It's mild dyslexia, I think.